# Datatables parent control in responsive datatables

Tags: datatables

Is it possible for me to control the displayed column rows in the parents table? 
for example if I have `ID, Name, Job, Salary, Age, birthdate.` if the window is minimized, the last column row which is `birthdate` will be displayed on the parents `td`. so instead of `ID, Name, Job, it will be ID, Name, Birthdate`.

any help regarding this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by setting responsivePriority for your column.
The priority is an integer value where lower numbers are given a higher priority (i.e. a column with priority 2 will be hidden before a column with priority 1).

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    responsive: true,
    columnDefs: [
        { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 5 },
    ]
} );
```

further more information you can see this link below: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.responsivePriority